# In Autohotkey how to wait until screen is on?

Tags: autohotkey, windows-scripting

I am using a script to switch between my TV and my monitor and also switching the audio (TV or speakers). My problem is, if the TV is not active the audio isn't in the speakers list, so I want to halt my script to wait until the TV is on. Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this code, gets all display devices. So all I needed to do is check if the device with the certain name exists...

```
CheckIfDisplayExists:
Gosub, GetDisplayDevices
For DeviceName, DeviceID in Devices
   {
        If (InStr(DeviceName, "SAMSUNG"))
        {
            ; < display exists, run the rest of the code >
        }
    }
```

This is the code to get all display devices:

```
GetDisplayDevices:
; http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/
Devices := {}
IMMDeviceEnumerator := ComObjCreate("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}", "{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}")

; IMMDeviceEnumerator::EnumAudioEndpoints
; eRender = 0, eCapture, eAll
; 0x1 = DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE
DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDeviceEnumerator+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDeviceEnumerator, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 0x1, "UPtrP", IMMDeviceCollection, "UInt")
ObjRelease(IMMDeviceEnumerator)

; IMMDeviceCollection::GetCount
DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDeviceCollection+0)+3*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDeviceCollection, "UIntP", Count, "UInt")
Loop % (Count)
{
    ; IMMDeviceCollection::Item
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDeviceCollection+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDeviceCollection, "UInt", A_Index-1, "UPtrP", IMMDevice, "UInt")

    ; IMMDevice::GetId
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDevice+0)+5*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtrP", pBuffer, "UInt")
    DeviceID := StrGet(pBuffer, "UTF-16"), DllCall("Ole32.dll\CoTaskMemFree", "UPtr", pBuffer)

    ; IMMDevice::OpenPropertyStore
    ; 0x0 = STGM_READ
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IMMDevice+0)+4*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UInt", 0x0, "UPtrP", IPropertyStore, "UInt")
    ObjRelease(IMMDevice)

    ; IPropertyStore::GetValue
    VarSetCapacity(PROPVARIANT, A_PtrSize == 4 ? 16 : 24)
    VarSetCapacity(PROPERTYKEY, 20)
    DllCall("Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}", "UPtr", &PROPERTYKEY)
    NumPut(14, &PROPERTYKEY + 16, "UInt")
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IPropertyStore+0)+5*A_PtrSize), "UPtr", IPropertyStore, "UPtr", &PROPERTYKEY, "UPtr", &PROPVARIANT, "UInt")
    DeviceName := StrGet(NumGet(&PROPVARIANT + 8), "UTF-16")    ; LPWSTR PROPVARIANT.pwszVal
    DllCall("Ole32.dll\CoTaskMemFree", "UPtr", NumGet(&PROPVARIANT + 8))    ; LPWSTR PROPVARIANT.pwszVal
    ObjRelease(IPropertyStore)

    ObjRawSet(Devices, DeviceName, DeviceID)
}
ObjRelease(IMMDeviceCollection)
return
```